# UITableView Reuse Causing Broken Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When scrolling my UITableView (tends to be when I scroll it fast) the data for my cells gets mixed up, so labels might be repeated etc.

I understand that reusing the cells probably causes this, but what if the user scrolls down the list really quickly and all the cells get mixed up, how am I supposed to avoid this?

Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VideoListCell";
    VideoListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[VideoListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    if (isPlaylistView)
    {
        //Fill cell with data
    }
    else if (isPlaylistDetailView || isSearchResultsView)
    {
        //Fill cell with data
    }
    else
    {
        //Playlist button and uploads
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            //Fill cell with data
        }
        else
        {
            //Fill cell with data
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Post your code, this way nobody can help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally use this kind of code:

```
cell = dequeReusableCell;
if (cell == nil) { 
    create cell;
    initialize cell;
}

fill cell with actual data from current row
return cell;
```

If you will move code "fill cell with actual data from current row" into "if" — you will get the kind of behavior you get right now.

So the answer will be "fill cell with data after you initialize it, outside of "if (cell == nil)" block.

Comment: This is just what I do at the moment. I added my code to my original question.

Comment: you don't have to do this in iOS6+ anymore, the system will initialize and return a new cell if there's no reusable cell.

Comment: So I don't need `if (cell == nil)`?

Comment: Do you have any background things going on inside "Fill cell with data"?

Comment: I do have some images get fetched on another thread using GCD as doing it on the same thread causes the table to freeze from time to time.

Comment: If you see problems with incorrectly filled cells, you should recheck code after "if (cell == nil)" It has to fill cells every (!) time when it is called. And has to set labels/images/cell states immediately. If you set cell data after (from another thread), this cell can already be used for some other cell. Also it's good to use different reuse-identifiers for different types of cells.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` will ever only dequeue a cell for reuse if the position that the cell was in is currently off-screen. So you don't have to worry about "mix-ups".

Comment: Well I do, because sometimes when cells com eon screen they are still reusing data from another cell, meaning they are displaying the wrong info.

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: I've tried this, and its fixes that but instead I get momentarily blank cells as it loads data in, trying to find the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `nil` for example..

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

**UPDATE:**

See this Example... i load many data in the cell with also my custom Gridview...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"gridCell";

    UITableViewCell *gridCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if(gridCell == nil)        
    {
        gridCell =  [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];


    }
    return gridCell;
}
```

hope this help you....

Comment: I've tried this, and its fixes that but instead I get momentarily blank cells as it loads data in, trying to find the best solution.

Comment: @JoshKahane you have xib for this cell??

Comment: I have a UITableViewController in my storyboard and that has a blank cell with my cell identifier, but I add all the subviews in a UITableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom cell class override `prepareForReuse` method. In this method set text of your labels to nil and set imageview's image to nil also. This function is called everytime when a cell is reused so your problem will be solved by this. May be like this

```
- (void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.titleLabel.text = nil;
    self.unitImageView.image = nil;
}
```